# How do i insert data in single row when i have multiple activities

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

Iam making a project in android studio,in my project UI i have created multiple activites for signup like one activity for name,age,gender other for email id and password,now my question is, how to enter these values from multiple activities in single row.

Answer (score 1):

You should use room database as described here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a common class like helper class. And in this class you can make some property name, age or password. And when an activity finish you can set the value of specific property. And then after last activity you can access common class properties to get each activity values.